# Efficient web crawling

Tags: java, web-crawler

What is a good way in java to achieve the following method i have come up with for fetching NEW web data for my database? Would comparing a bunch of array elements be the way to go? Some ideas would be great.

```
Crawler imdbCrawler = new Crawler(files.getLocalTitles("C:\\Movies"));
//add these titles to the database
//query to get existing DB titles, get directory titles and crawl negated union of these titles
```

Comment: More info on what you're trying to accomplish and what you've tried would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know, [IMDB offers their database for free](http://www.imdb.com/interfaces)... with some caveats of course for commercial use.

Second, using some kind of structure/Collection would be best, so if the object in the collection HAS data, it means you've crawled it already. If it does not, it still needs crawling. If you find a new link, just add it to the collection (with no data), and your data collection thread will find those later.

Dekker